# Elijo la presentación del producto y no muestra su imagen Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Hola tengo el siguiente inconveniente
cuando selecciono un producto configurable muestra el producto padre y la opción de elegir la presentación del producto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando selecciono la presentacion del producto no muestra la imagen asociada a esta presentacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la consola del navegador dice que no encuetra la imagen en la carpeta cache asi

```
/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/460a3bcb…35aac43a6f81f8f135/j/a/jabon_quirurgico_wescohex_jabon_2_x_120_ml_west.png 404 (Not Found)
```

La imagen existe en el siguiente directorio    pub/media/catalog/product/j/a/jabon_quirurgico_wescohex_jabon_2_x_30_ml_west_1.png

De que forma se debe generar esta imagen para ser mostrada

Comment: ¿El sitio fue transferido de otra parte o la imagen fue subida en ese servidor directamente?

Comment: ¿Como subiste esa imagen?

Comment: esta todo en localhost en pub/media y en la tabla catalog_product_entity_media_gallery la dirección de las imagenes asi /j/a/jabon_quirurgico_wescohex_jabon_2_x_30_ml_west_1.png

Comment: ¿Aún así no respondiste la pregunta, el archivo fue subido o importado o el el sitio fue transferido?

Comment: fue en la migracion de la version magento 1.7 a la version 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el sitio fue migrado desde Magento 1.x es muy probable que las imágenes del caché no estén generadas, por lo cual debes hacerlo "de forma manual".

Normalmente esto lo haces con el comando `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize`, de esa forma podrás regenerar todos los tamaños que estén especificados en el view.xml del theme actual y los otros themes de los cuales herede.

Comment: Usando ese comando me aparece como error `[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]  
  Area code is already set`

Comment: Tal vez tienes algún otro comando personalizado que está "seteando" el Area code en el constructor y esto genera ese tipo de conflictos.